# Question about separable extension and $f(x)=x^{p^n}-a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in F which the leading coefficient is 1 and its degree is larger than 2. Show that if $f(x)$ has the same root in its splitting field, then the characteristic of F is $p>0$(prime), and $f(x)=x^{p^n}-a \in F[x], n\ge 1$.

I'm confused how to solve this question using the separable extension, please give me some hints. Thanks!

Comment: If $f$ has a repeated root $t$, then $t$ is a root of its derivative $f’$. But $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $t$, so divides every polynomial over $F$ having $t$ as a root. So $f$ divides $f’$. Now compare degrees.

Comment: I see and I have some idea about it. Thank you!